# Form script only shows up when it's placed in footer section

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a really odd issue. I'm using a form app and want to embed the embed code into click funnels.

The code is the following:

```html
<script type=“text/javascript“ src=“https://MY-DOMAIN.DE/wp-content/plugins/Anfrageformular-pro/res/scripts/af2_iframe_data.js“ data-url=“https://MY-DOMAIN.DE/“ data-content-id=“XXXX“></script>
```

It seems that the solution would be something like this:

"An extension that function the file wait for the elements to load, namely: `<body onload="functionAllJS();">` or `document.onload = function () {//HERE_CODE_JS}` or `window.onload = function(){//HERE_CODE_JS}` "

But... I don't know what to do with that or how to use that in Clickfunnels sadly.

The only real explanation for this behavior seems to be "This is because methods and statements in JavaScript files don't work until after the elements (DOM tree) you are working on has been loaded Unlike style files that work at any time (CSS)"

But again, I wonder how to make this work now

Comment: FYI: You didnt add any code

Comment: Cause I'm an idiot! Now it's there and displaying fine  I guess :-) Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Okay after I found out the html version of "window.load" it seems to be easy:

```html
<window onload="myFunction()"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.de/wp-content/plugins/Anfrageformular-pro/res/scripts/af2_iframe_data.js" data-url="https://domain.de/" data-content-id="1024" data-maps-key="key"></script>
```

That code makes it possible to load the form on the page directly. When I try to embed the same code on a popup that triggers once a button is clicked it still wont load the form.

Wonder if there is any other command / piece of code to make it trigger after a button was clicked